# Build failure in Jenkins after failed test MSTest

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, jenkins, msbuild, mstest

In Jenkins I create a Visual studio project using MSBuild. After the build I  execute a windows batch command that executes the tests en sets the output file.

Post build I publish the .trx test report file. This all works perfect, the only problem is that if a test fails the build fails. With other types of projects if a test fails the build only becomes unstable.

How can I do the same for my Visual studio project?

Below my batch command:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:TestAppTests\bin\Debug\TestAppTests.dll /resultsfile:TestResults.trx

Answer (score 0):

I know it's pretty old but here are something as I've encountered the same type of problem.

**Using Batch:**
At the end of that batch command step where you run the tests, add one more exit command, such as `exit /b 0` or `exit 0`.

---

**Using Powershell:**
At the end of the powershell command step where you run the tests, same, manually set the exit code `$LastExitCode = 0`.

---

**Final:**
The result will always be set to success no matter how many tests failed so you need to parse and analyze the result yourself. There are tools such as: https://plugins.jenkins.io/mstest and https://plugins.jenkins.io/xunit.